# Java decryption is failing to decrypt a CryptoJS encrypted data

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes, decoding, cryptojs

I am using AES/CBC algorithm. I am open to use any padding mechanism.

Javascript encrypt code:

```
var text = "test@gmail.com";
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("lzi839AEKDDDtQN63+eTZbhJrLq/cn62oqH23IrqoMY=");

//Trying to generate 16 null bytes, Equivalent to java code : "new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16])". Not sure if this is correct.
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv: iv, mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
console.log("Encrypted String:: "+encrypted.toString());
```

This produces following output:

```
Encrypted String:: jcmI/BhSDa8yhWNoFLIF6g==
```

Following is the Java decryption code:

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedString, String key) throws SecurityException {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = getCipher();
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, 
                        new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(key),"AES"), 
                        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString), 0, 32);
            return new String(decryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Fail to decrypt", e);
        }
    }
```

When I call the above java function as :

```
String encryptedString = "jcmI/BhSDa8yhWNoFLIF6g==";
String key = "lzi839AEKDDDtQN63+eTZbhJrLq/cn62oqH23IrqoMY=";

decrypt(encryptedString, key);
```

I get below exception message:

```
**Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption**
```

I Referred a similar question : [Why can't java decrypt CryptoJS encrypted data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125317/why-cant-java-decrypt-cryptojs-encrypted-data)

But this is in ECB mode and it did not help me completely to arrive at my solution.

Please help me to fix this error and decrypt properly at Java end. I am open to change Padding methods. However, I must use AES/CBC mode only.

Update:

Full code for Java Decryption:

```
public String decrypt(String encryptedString, String key) throws SecurityException {
        try {
            Cipher cipher =Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, 
                        new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decodeBase64(key),"AES"), 
                        new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
            byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString), 0, 32);
            return new String(decryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SecurityException("Fail to decrypt", e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the CryptoJS code the Base64 encoder must be used instead of the Hex encoder regarding the key. In `doFinal()` the last two parameters have to be omitted. Note that a static IV is insecure and that `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` is only guessed because `getCipher()` is missing.

Comment: @Topaco, thank you for your response. I tried using CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse() for both key and iv. Now I am seeing a different error in Java decrypt function, i.e. while executing cipher.doFinal(), "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad arguments".

Fyi, I am using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding.

Comment: No, the Base64 encoder only for the key, not for the IV. For the IV you still have to use the Hex encoder.

Comment: Also please let me know if this(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");
) is the right way to create "iv", similar to that of Java (new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]))

Comment: @Topaco, I used Base64 encoder only for the key. I did not see any difference in the encrypted string generated.


`var key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("lzi839AEKDDDtQN63+eTZbhJrLq/cn62oqH23IrqoMY=");

var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse("00000000000000000000000000000000");

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(text, key, {iv: iv});


Output: OrVDnwhd2E+sLyQLCS5XMA==`

Comment: Right. Both correspond to a zero IV, i.e. an IV consisting of 16 0x00 values (which is as insecure as any other static IV).

Comment: _...I did not see any difference in the encrypted string generated..._ `OrVDnwhd2E+sLyQLCS5XMA==` differs from `jcmI/BhSDa8yhWNoFLIF6g==`, isn't it? And decryption of `OrVDnwhd2E+sLyQLCS5XMA==` with the Java code taking into account the mentioned changes provides the plaintext.

Comment: Very sorry for the confusion created. I am seeing the same error at Java end. i.e. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad arguments`.
I used Base64 for key and Hex coding for iv parameter.

Comment: I can't reproduce that. Please post the currently used Java code including the call and `getCipher()`.

Comment: @Topaco, in your first comment you had asked me to Omit the last two params from doFinal. Totally missed that. It's working. You are amazing!! Thanks a lot :)